# Problem accessing global variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working on google maps and I need to create an array of items. Here is my pseudo code:

```
<script>
var myvar=new array();

function initialize(){
   for i=1 to 10
   {  
        callAnotherFunct(i);
   }

   access myvar() here; 
}


function callAnotherFunct(i){
    myvar=array_element_i;
}

</script>
```

I am expecting myvar to behave as a global variable but it is not. I cannot get any values for myvar in the initialize().

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can we see the actual code, please? It may help spot the problem

Comment: is this pseudocode? bc if this is your real code it wont do anything, it is completely **wrong**

Comment: How are you accessing the values?

Comment: Why not post *real* code? What's the thinking behind providing us with a mangled version of something that you must surely have tried in real JavaScript?

Comment: `var myGlobalVar = {}` and then use something like `myGlobalVar.myArray = new Array()` Probably a namespace collision. I had the same issue and using a separate namespace seemed to work :)

Comment: The actual code has lot of stuff going on. I will need quite a lot of time to clean it up. What I have posted is the pseudo code. I cannot assign values to the array. Do I need to pass the index while assigning a value to the array? How can I add the value to array here? I will probably have to use index for myvar then. It is simple case of assigning values to array in one function and using it in other.

Comment: @Blueboye You don't have to pass an index if you don't care about the order, you can just use `myvar.length` as the next index.  Also, `array_element_i` will need to be a global variable in your "pseudo" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you were trying to accomplish, but I was able to make several modifications and was able to access the global variable in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/pKU6A/

```
var myvar=new Array(); //Array should be uppercase

function initialize(){
   for (var i=1; i < 10; i++) //incorrect for loop syntax
   {  
        callAnotherFunct(i);
   }

  alert(myvar);
}


function callAnotherFunct(i){
    myvar[i] = i; //local variable was not defined and index of array must be assigned
}

initialize(); //needed to call global function to kick it off
```

Answer (score 2):

pseudo-schmeudo.

```
var myvar = [];

function initialize(){
   for (var i=0; i < 10; i++)
   {  
        callAnotherFunct(i);
   }

   alert(myvar[0]);
   alert(myvar[9]);
}


function callAnotherFunct(i){
    myvar[i]=i + 'pseudo-schmeudo';
}

initialize();
```

[Fiddle-schmiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/RmJus/).

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AKKHB/

Seems to be ok

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell what you might be doing wrong - with the pseudocode.

I have de-pseudified your code and it works fine:

```
var myvar=new Array();

function initialize(){
  for (i=1; i < 10; i++)
  {  
    callAnotherFunct(i);
  }
  alert(myvar);
  //access myvar() here; 
}

function callAnotherFunct(i){
  myvar.push(i);
}
```

when you call initialize() - it will alert with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
window.myvar = []; // don't use new Array()

function initialize(){
   for i=1 to 10
   {  
        callAnotherFunct(i);
   }

   //window.myvar or myvar here should work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing this is a namespace issue. Do something like this

```
window.project = window.project || {};
project.vars = project.vars || {};

Then you will have a namespace declaration, so you can do

project.vars.myVar = new Array();
```

That's the only issue I could think of