# How to pass the value of an innerHTML element to a global variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, global, innerhtml, getelementbyid

New to Javascript/HTML5, apologies if the terminologies don't make sense

How do  you set a global variable to have the same value (preferably int or double) as an innerHTML element from one function, then use the global variable to control a loop in another function?

I'm trying to set up a loop that counts up every second as long as an innerHTML element 'avgSpeed' is between 0 and 60. 
There are two functions, one populates the elements and second one is the loop. I can't get the loop to work with the value I read from the elements from the first function.

Within the first function, I populate the element 'avgSpeed':

```
document.getElementById("avgSpeed").innerHTML = (responseObj.average_speed!=undefined)?responseObj.average_speed: "Not available";
```

This works fine, if I print the element in my HTML file, the page will display my avgSpeed (example: 30 or 40, NOT displayed as 30.0 or 40.0)

I have tried the following: *`var miles` is the global variable I'm using*

```
miles=document.getElementById("avgSpeed").innerHTML;
miles=parseInt(document.getElementById("avgSpeed").innerHTML);
```

I just can't link the 'avgSpeed' to a global variable to be used as loop control. 
Thank you!

Comment: Where is the loop? Where are the variables defined? When/how are you accessing the variable(s)? Since this is a scope question, posting your exact setup is important.

Comment: The loop is in another function, separate from avgSpeed.
Var miles is defined outside of any functions, so a global variable.

Comment: See if there is anything to prompt your solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291252/javascript-global-variables

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass the value of an innerHTML to a global variable...
Sample Code

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getValue() 
{ 
var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML);  
x=x+3;  
alert(x);  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="myHeader" onclick="getValue()">123</h1>
</body>
</html>`
```

i hope this will help you!

Comment: Is var x global for this code even if it's defined within the function getValue?
I've tried:
miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("avgSpeed").innerHTML);

Miles defined outside the function

Comment: Hey, why not just attach it to the window object? and also refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601222/problem-accessing-global-variable-in-javascript